# Refreshing/Updating DataGridView on PC X and Y according to SQL Table update

Tags: c#, mysql

I made a program to track maintenance progress for my company and everything is fine till now, but after thinking for a while, We have 7 branches + Maintenance center, What I was thinking about is if Branch X added a new device to the list, the Maintenance center need to press on a refresh button to retrieve the DB once again, So I was wondering how can I make the DataGridView updates itself across all the 7 branches, If X branch added something or edited, Y and Z branch can get the real-time update? I've searched a lot for it but I couldn't find anything, or maybe I can't describe what I wanted to Google.

Ideas Though to do it:

1. Make a timer every 5 mins to automatic get the data again from SQL, but it will make a huge load since it will be around 7 PCs making queries every 5 mins + maybe the Customer service department will have a minimum of 3 PCs on the same program so it will be a load on the SQL.

Comment: Realtime? Network connections to a server. Consider SignalR; look at any "how to write a chat program with signalR" type tutorial - the 7 computers are chatting, and it's quite a boring conversation, mainly "I've updated" notes..

Comment: *so it will be a load on the SQL* - it really wouldn't. Even if every PC in the company is doing a `SELECT * FROM devices WHERE lastModifiedDate > @lastKnownDate` (and any insert or update sets the new modified date, an indexed column) (and the program just supplies the max date that it knows about), once a second your database wouldn't even blink..

Comment: I will check SignalR, But SignalR works with Winform or only ASP.Net ? But overall making a timer is enough or Making SignalR chat is better ?

Comment: Yes, you can get a winforms single client, but if 5 minutes resolution on the db will suffice, just do that.. like I say, it could even be a second and it would be fine.. just craft your query so it's light